# How to run ./ script with crontabl

Tags: cron

I want to run my script which is `./fc` every 5 minutes which the default crontab command is 
`*/5 * * * * /path/to/script-or-program` but how would i merge ./ in with it ?

Comment: Why can't you specify the full path to `fc`?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not `./fc`. It's `fc`. The `./` is a relative path, and means "current directory". So use the absolute path instead. You can find the absolute path to your current directory with:

```
pwd
```

This might print something like:

```
/home/you
```

So you'd use this path in your crontab:

```
/home/you/fc
```

Another way to get the absolute path is using the `realpath` command:

```
realpath fc
```

This will print the absolute path to the file you pass as argument.